# Directory being deleted randomly by unknown script

Tags: php, image, mysqli, directory

I have set up a simple "Facebook" like timeline system for my friend to be able to upload statuses with images for his users to see. It seemed to all be working well although the file which stores the images keeps being deleted, and I can't seem to purposely cause the problem myself so I have no idea what is removing this directory?

I have added the upload/remove scripts below to see if anybody might be able to assist me here? I can't seem to find any part of the script which would delete the main image directory on its own?

PLEASE BARE IN MIND - This is still unfinished, and is nowhere near secure just yet, we are in testing phase and need to fix this problem before I can work on perfecting the system.

The main folder for storage of the images is `post_images`, this is the directory which is being deleted.

REMOVE DIR FUNCTION -

```
function rrmdir($dir) {
  foreach(glob($dir . '/*') as $file) { 
    if(is_dir($file)) rrmdir($file); else unlink($file); 
  } 
  rmdir($dir); 
}
```

DECLINE POSTS -

```
if(isset($_GET['decline_post'])){
    $post_id = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['decline_post']);

    $getimagefolder = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `post_image_folder` FROM `Pto6LsuQ_posts` WHERE `post_id` = '$post_id'"));
     $image_folder = $getimagefolder['post_image_folder'];


    mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM `Pto6LsuQ_posts` WHERE `post_id` = '$post_id'");

    $direc = 'post_images/'.$image_folder;

if (file_exists($direc)) {

rrmdir($direc);

} else {
}

    header("Location: members_area.php");
}
```

DELETE POST -

```
if(isset($_GET['delete_post'])){
    $post_id = $conn->real_escape_string($_GET['delete_post']);

    $getimagefolder = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `post_image_folder` FROM `Pto6LsuQ_posts` WHERE `post_id` = '$post_id'"));
     $image_folder = $getimagefolder['post_image_folder'];


    mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM `Pto6LsuQ_posts` WHERE `post_id` = '$post_id'");

    $direc = 'post_images/'.$image_folder;

if (file_exists($direc)) {

rrmdir($direc);

} else {
}

    header("Location: members_area.php");
}
```

UPLOAD POST -

```
if(isset($_POST['new_post'])){
    $post_status = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['status']);
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    if(!empty($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'])){


       $length = 9; 
       $search = true; // allow the loop to begin
       while($search == true) {
             $rand_image_folder = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789"), 0, $length);
             if (!file_exists('../post_images/'.$rand_image_folder)) {  
                 $search = false;
             }  
        }

        mkdir("../post_images/".$rand_image_folder);

      foreach($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
           $file_name = $key.$_FILES['images']['name'][$key];
           $file_size = $_FILES['images']['size'][$key];
           $file_tmp = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key];
           $file_type = $_FILES['images']['type'][$key];

           $check_file_type = substr($file_type, 0, strrpos( $file_type, '/'));

           if($check_file_type !== 'image'){
               header('Location: ../members_area.php?posterror=1');
           }

           $extensions = array("jpeg","jpg","png","JPEG","JPG","PNG"); 

           $format = trim(substr($file_type, strrpos($file_type, '/') + 1));

             if(in_array($format,$extensions) === false){
             header('Location: ../members_area.php?posterror=1');
             } else {   

             move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"../post_images/".$rand_image_folder."/".$file_name);

             $file = "../post_images/".$rand_image_folder."/".$file_name;


$cut_name = substr($file, strpos($file, "/") + 1);  
$cut_name = explode('/',$cut_name); 
$cut_name = end($cut_name); 

             $newfile = "../post_images/".$rand_image_folder."/thb_".$cut_name;
             $info = getimagesize($file);
             list($width, $height) = getimagesize($file);

                 $max_width = '350';
                 $max_height = '250';

                 //try max width first...
                      $ratio = $max_width / $width;
                      $new_width = $max_width;
                      $new_height = $height * $ratio;

                 //if that didn't work
                    if ($new_height > $max_height) {
                        $ratio = $max_height / $height;     
                        $new_height = $max_height;
                        $new_width = $width * $ratio;
                    }

    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') $image = imagecreatefromgif($file);
    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
            $image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
            $photo = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
            imagecopyresampled($image, $photo, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);


            imagejpeg($image, $newfile, 70);        


             }
        }

    if($account_type < 4){
        $post_public = 1;
    } else {
        $post_public = 0;
    }

      mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `Pto6LsuQ_posts`   
              (post_id,post_user_id,post_date_time,post_status,post_image_folder,post_likes,post_public_status)
       VALUES ('','$user_id',NOW(),'$post_status','$rand_image_folder','0','$post_public')");

    } else {


        if($account_type < 4){
        $post_public = 1;
    } else {
        $post_public = 0;
    }

        mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `Pto6LsuQ_posts`   
              (post_id,post_user_id,post_date_time,post_status,post_image_folder,post_likes,post_public_status)
       VALUES ('','$user_id',NOW(),'$post_status','','0','$post_public')");


    }

    header('Location: ../members_area.php?posterror=2');


}
```

Comment: what's the value of `$direc = 'post_images/'.$image_folder;` ? when you echo this variable `$direc` what it does return ?

Comment: it seems to return as null , because of that the main folder is deleted

Comment: It should return a result from a search on a MySQLi database table query and the produce the ID of the folder in which the images are stored. Although I can see that if the search comes back negative, then the value will return as null?

Comment: when you echo this `$direc` ? what's the output